# Basic spectral geometry question for surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, spectral-theory

Assume that $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth, compact, properly embedded surface with boundary $\partial S = \gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2$, where $\gamma_i$ are smooth closed curves. Moreover assume that $S$ is diffeomorphic to an annulus.

If I know the value of the first Dirichlet eigenvalue of $S$, what kind of geometric information do I get? Can I have an estimate on the area, for example?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Consider the round cylinder of radius $a$ and length $b$. The first Dirichlet eigenvalue is proportional to $\frac{1}{b^2}$ (independent of $a$) and the area is proportional to $a b$. So I don't think the first eigenvalue can give an estimate on the area.

Comment: @PhillipAndreae Thanks for the comment! Can you give me an intuition about why the first eigenvalue doesn´t depend on $a$?

Comment: I'm not sure about intuition. But I will say that it's essential that you're studying the Dirichlet eigenvalues on a product manifold with boundary, as opposed to eigenvalues on a product manifold without boundary. For example, on the flat torus $S^1(a) \times S^1(b)$, the first (nonzero) eigenvalue is the minimum of $\frac{1}{a^2}$ and $\frac{1}{b^2}$, where $a$ and $b$ are the respective radii.

Comment: I'm happy to discuss this further if you have more questions I could attempt to answer. I could write some of this as an answer instead of a comment, but I didn't think I had a complete enough answer to your question.